# Cannot resolve symbol 'menu'

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: MainActivity.java]

> This activity_main.java

## Main javaActity file

*imported packages and libraries*

```
//Package for project 
package com.example.legend.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

//Main activity main class extending Activity class

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //Menu class

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);//Can't resolve  menu symbol
        return true;
    }
}
```

> Manifest.xml file

## AndroidManifest.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.legend.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

> String.xml file
>
> ### String Content file for app

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">XXXXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

> activity_main.xml
>
> ## Activity_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#da006699"
tools:context="com.example.legend.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="XXXXXXXXX"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you have a directory called `res/menu` that contains `menu.xml`?

Comment: Menu file missing in your layout folder

Comment: you have to create menu file under res folder .

Answer (score 1):

Since, your `@Override` is showing error too, that means the method is not found on the super class. That is true because `AppCompatActivity` does not have a:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu)
```

However, it does have a:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){...} // Option -> Options
```

So, you need to make above change. Other than that make sure you have the `menu_main.xml` in `res/menu` directory.